# Java EE o Pagina HTML en Java Application Netbeans

Tags: java, java-ee, javafx

Quisiera que alguien me saque de unas dudas.

Tengo una aplicación web con Java EE en Netbeans ya lista, osea se ejecuta en el navegador de prueba y todo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber si puedo utilizar esta aplicación web en una Java Application normal es decir para que se ejecute en una computadora como programa de escritorio tipo una webview, intente hacer una Webview y se puede visualizar la pagina web en la java application pero e igual que en el Android Studio quisiera que se pueda interactuar entre si es decir que desde la java application pueda controlar acciones en la java web y viceversa.

Comment: Lo dudo mucho. Una Java Web View funciona como un navegador; ni la JWV sabe de dónde le viene el HTML ni el servidor java sabe qué hará la aplicación cliente con el HTML; son responsabilidades separadas. Además, si una JWV permitiera que el servidor la controlara (más allá del HTML), probablemente sería un riesgo de seguridad muy grande.

Comment: Si quieres una aplicación de escritorio, con funcionalidad de aplicación de escritorio, lo suyo es una aplicación de escritorio. Que se encargue de la visualización de los datos, y que obtenga los datos comunicándose con el servidor (webservices/REST/lo que sea). Ayuda si tienes el diseño del servidor bien estructurado en tres capas (la lógica de negocio la tienes en clases que son independientes de la capa de presentación)